# Size and Alignment in GraphicsRow[....]

Tags: graphics

I just ran into a problem with `GraphicsRow`. Here an example (I want to combine a `BarChart` and a `PairedBarChart`), so...

```
{l1, l2} = RandomInteger[#, 20] & /@ {10, 10};
```

and:

```
g1 = BarChart[l1, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

and

```
g2 = PairedBarChart[l1, l2,
  ChartLabels -> Range[20],
  AxesLabel -> {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}
  ]
```

Then `GraphicsRow` delivers:

```
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}]
```

Output (look at the borders of `GraphicsRow`):

[image: GraphicsRow unaligned]

Now the graphs are not aligned, so I used an alignment (`Bottom` in `GraphicsRow`), and got:

```
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image: <code>GraphicsRow</code>with alignment at bottom]

O.K. the graphs are aligned, but why this large surrounding box?

**Update...**

If I add a frame, everything is fine???

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `AspectRatio->Full` then it works without having to use `Frame` nor `Alignment`

```
{l1,l2} = RandomInteger[#,20]&/@{10,10};
g1      = BarChart[l1,BarOrigin->Left,AspectRatio->Full]
g2      = PairedBarChart[l1,l2,ChartLabels->Range[20],
           AxesLabel->{"Horizontal","Vertical"},AspectRatio->Full]
```

Now

```
GraphicsRow[{g1,g2},ImageSize->700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

fyi, I noticed with this method, if the final imagesize is small, the numerical values in the right images in the middle there (the ones from 1..20, become harder to read as they do not scale.

Comment: This works fine for me -so accepted as answer. But if you use `Alignment->Bottom` your get again the large surrounding box. What I also wonder about is that the alignment regards to the numbers at the tick-marks not the horizontal axes

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `Grid`. If you dont need frame just remove `Frame@` in the code.

```
   SeedRandom[123];
{l1, l2} = RandomInteger[10, {2, 20}];

g1 = BarChart[l1, BarOrigin -> Left, ImageSize -> 350];

g2 = PairedBarChart[l1, l2, ChartLabels -> Range[20], 
   AxesLabel -> {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}, ImageSize -> 450];

Framed@Grid[{{g1, Spacer[2], g2}}, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]